# Set knockout css binding based on item in observable array

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

Whenever I save my item I remap the model doing the following:

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, deal);
```

My model looks like:

```
{
  "DealId": 0,
  "BrokenRules": [
    {
      "Property": "EndDate",
      "Description": "End Date is required."
    },
    {
      "Property": "CustomerId",
      "Description": "Customer is required."
    },
    {
      "Property": "LiveState",
      "Description": "Live State is required."
    },
    {
      "Property": "WorkState",
      "Description": "Work State is required."
    }
}
```

I want to set the css class on a `div` based on the contents of the `BrokenRules` array and was hoping I could do something like:

```
    <div class="control-group" data-bind="css: { error: BrokenRules.filterByProperty('Property', 'EndDate').length !== 0 }">
        <label class="control-label">End Date</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" class="span2" name="EndDate" data-bind="value: EndDate, enable: $index() === 0" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

But this doesn't seem to work. My filterByProperty, while firing the first time, doesn't have any items, and for some reason, never fires again.

```
ko.observableArray.fn.filterByProperty = function (propName, matchValue) {
    return ko.computed(function () {
        var allItems = this(), matchingItems = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < allItems.length; i++) {
            var current = allItems[i];
            if (ko.utils.unwrapObservable(current[propName]) === matchValue)
                matchingItems.push(current);
        }
        return matchingItems;
    }, this);
}
```

The filterByProperty was taken right from the knockoutjs site.

Any help on doing this would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `filterByProperty` function is returning a `ko.computed`.  In order to get the actual array, you need to execute the computed to get the underlying JavaScript array, and then you can check the length.

Notice the extra parentheses after `filterByProperty()`

```
<div class="control-group" data-bind="css: { error: BrokenRules.filterByProperty('Property', 'EndDate')().length !== 0 }">
```

[**See the Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/blugrasmaniac/MPAS4/)

Comment: That worked perfectly! I swear those extra parentheses are going to be the death of me! :)

Comment: If you set up your computed to return an observableArray, then you could have two sets of them :)